How to make object is always within the camera frame with drivers?
 I need help with creating and configuring drivers for object location depending on camera resolution. So, the point is that the object (plane) should always be within the camera frame regardless of its resolution. Thus, if the camera boundaries change relative to the X or Y axis, the plane should also shift relative to the frame boundaries along these axes in order to always remain within the frame.
